# Building UWP packages for KONY application by using command line interface

Tags: uwp, continuous-integration, azure-devops, command-line-interface, temenos-quantum

I am trying to build UWP packages for Kony application, using command line interface. Seems the [official doc](http://docs.kony.com/konylibrary/visualizer/visualizer_user_guide/Content/BuildApplicationsForWindows10.htm) describes the building process by using IDE. However I am trying to build using VSTS/CI/CD workflow where command line build is preferable.  Any suggestions how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: self comment, found this link useful - http://docs.kony.com/konylibrary/visualizer/visualizer_user_guide/Content/CommandLine.htm

Comment: Thanks, Nico, will do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process is described as [headless build](http://docs.kony.com/konylibrary/visualizer/visualizer_user_guide/Content/CommandLine.htm), in official Kony documentation.